# How can I take my captured information from a network/port scan and write that to a file?

Tags: sockets, python-3.5

I wrote an IP and port scanning program and I want to take the captured data and output it to a text file. I've been trying to figure it out for a while and haven't had any luck applying what I can find in searches. At the end, I commented out how I thought it should work to write the information to a file.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm still somewhat new to Python and trying to learn.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ipaddress
import sys, time
import os
import subprocess
import socket
from datetime import datetime

FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)


print ('Welcome to the IP/Port Scanner and Logger')
address = input('Enter starting IP address: ')
split1 = first,second,third,fourth = str(address).split('.')
start = int(fourth)

host = first+'.'+second+'.'+third+'.'+str(start)
end_address = input('Enter the ending IP address: ')
split2 = first,second,third,fourth = str(end_address).split('.')
end = int(fourth)

network = first+'.'+second+'.'+third+'.'

min_port = input("Enter starting port range: ")
max_port = input("Enter ending port range: ")



remoteserver = host
remoteserverIP = socket.gethostbyname(remoteserver)

def port_scan():
    print ('Port scanning function initialized:')
    try:
        for port in range(int(min_port),int(max_port)):  
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            result = sock.connect_ex((remoteserverIP, port))
            if result == 0:
                print ('Port ' + str(port) + ': Open')
            sock.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("You halted the process")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
        sys.exit()

    except socket.error:
        print ("Couldn't connect to server")
        sys.exit()
    return port

def check_up():
    for ip_address in range(int(start), int(end)):
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '2',
                                   network + str(ip_address)],
                                  stdout=FNULL,stderr=FNULL)
        except (OSError, subprocess.CalledProcessError):
            print ("{}{}".format(network,ip_address), "is down")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print ("You halted the process")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print ("{}{}".format(network,ip_address), "is up")
    return ip_address



check_up()


time1 = datetime.now()



time2 = datetime.now()
scantime = time2-time1
print ('Scan completed in: ', scantime)


while True:
    print ('Would you like to write information to file?')
    answer = input()
    if answer in ['yes', 'y', 'yeah']:
        print ('Alright, writing to file')
        print ('Program will exit upon scan completion.')
        break
    elif answer in ['no', 'n']:
        print ('Okay, exiting now..')
        sys.exit()
        break
    else:
        print ('Please enter a yes or no value')


###Output File
##with open('ipscan.txt', 'w+') as ip:
##   print (ip_address, port)
##
##sys.exit()
```